# Animation Nodes - How do I read the Particle Count with the Object Attribute Output node?

Tags: animation, scripting, node-editor, particles, animation-nodes

I am currently trying to drive the particle count of various instances of an object (containing a particleSystem) dynamically for each instance.

I'm using a loop subprogram with an Object Attribute Output node.

The one thing I can't seem to get right is how to point to the particle count in the Attribute Output node.

What I need is basically a one-line version of this:

```
bpy.data.objects['Plane'].modifiers['ParticleSystem 1']
bpy.data.particles['ParticleSettings'].count = value
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update with Node-Setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full python line to read that setting is:

```
bpy.data.objects['Plane'].particle_systems['ParticleSystem'].settings.count
```

According to the Animation Nodes documentation the attribute field of the Object Attribute Output node is relative to the object which would mean you would use:

```
particle_systems['ParticleSystem'].settings.count
```

or alternatively:

```
modifiers['ParticleSystem'].particle_system.settings.count
```

Whether this actually works is dependant on how the developer wrote the Animation Nodes addon.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly it didn't work. "Attribute not found" I updated my post with the node setup.

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't produce an error within the node. But all nodes objects still have identical particle counts. In this thread [link]http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45985/animation-nodes-is-it-possible-to-instance-nested-instances the author of the addon used `modifiers["Array"].count`

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You are replacing the 'ParticleSystem' string with the actual value in use correct?

Comment: sorry, I hit "Enter" a little too early - still have to get used to that. - Yes, I tried it with "ParticleSystem 1" which is the actual name. I also tried `modifiers['ParticleSystem 1'].settings.count` which also returns an error.

Comment: You can only have one particle count for the 'ParticleSystem' particle system. If all the object nodes are pointing to the one particle system, the count will be the same.

Comment: Your alternate syntax should read:
modifiers['ParticleSystem 1'].particle_system.settings.count but I'm not sure that's your issue if all your object references are pointing to the same particle system and you want them to have different particle counts.

Comment: Oh you are right!! The instancer node only creates new instances of the object, but uses the same particle system. Duh! It felt so close! ^^  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Then your answer is totally right. Only now I have to find the right question to ask. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

after some research and tests this code works for me:

```
modifiers["name"].particle_system.settings.count
```

where "name" is the text string used in the modifiers tab

IMPORTANT
You must set an input in the value slot 
otherwise it gives an error "Value has a wrong type"

[image]