# AN Loop over Group over Loop?

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]

Something that I missed and not understand too well is how the Matrix apply in Animation Nodes, and whether it is similar to Sverhok or not?

Kind of want to emulate Array Modifier stacks, using AN.

So basically I start with "object duplication" just to make like a 360 FAN. Just a simple rotation.

Then, I was thinking, ok maybe I can Group this setup. Which I did. But the Object Instancer cannot be within group.

Next, I was thinking, ok this Group needs to be duplicated, but here I stuck. Suddenly, this is not working.

Any idea?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fY7TOPLsO9s) and [this QA](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45985/animation-nodes-is-it-possible-to-instance-nested-instances/46020#46020) for better understaning on how matrix works in AN.

Comment: Thanks Leon, I'll investigate and study this. that's exactly it.

Comment: Looks like the issue I encountered is very similar, trying to loop Object Instancer. 

At some point Leon mentioned about Empty cannot be duplicated, but probably now can and we can cheat using Dupli Group or something.

Probably I was trying to do recursion of some sort.... well but not really but just curious if we can do it "that" way.

In simple case, it's almost like multiple Array Modifier stacks.

1) Rings of object
2) Duplicated along Path, somewhat making like a tentacle or worms
3) Next, reusing all above to create multiple Worms....

Maybe this is the limitation?

Comment: In that QA, the basic concept of Jacques' solution is to kinda trim/divide all instaners into sections/groups, I think that could be a better try.