# Matrix Parenting or Global Transform

Tags: animation-nodes

Another animation nodes and Matrix related question.

I have this setup of circular formation of objects. I use Matrix Combine to set this up, and then I group it.

Now, I just want a simple Matrix Transformation that will transform the setup as a whole. I cannot do that. I wonder how to do this simple parenting.

I tried Matrix Math, but it is not working. Especially with rotation, I cannot easily rotate just the whole thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The *Replicate Matrices Node* can be used, for instance, I can replicate a group of circularly distributed matrices on another group of circularly distributed matrices as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

This can be understood by viewing both inputs. You see that the blue matrices were copied and transformed to each of the green matrices:

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figure it out after investigating Jacques ORBIT CIRCLE example. I just need to add another Matrix at the very bottom of Matrix List.

[Animation Nodes: Is it possible to instance nested instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45985/animation-nodes-is-it-possible-to-instance-nested-instances)